# ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS : Need Intent to All Apps List

Tags: android, android-intent, android-9.0-pie, battery-saver

I need an intent to "Don't optimize" settings page of ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS  .

But when i change it to "Don't optimize and return , The settings are not saved .
It will be still in the "Optimized" list

Device :one Plus 5
Os : Android 9.0

Code :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Issue :
Settings are  not saved .

Also is there an intent available to "Battery optimized apps list ?"

Answer (score 10):

Try this to request REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS.

- Add this to Manifest

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />`
- Use this function to request optimization.

  ```
  public static void BatteryOptimization(Context context){
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      String packageName = context.getPackageName();
      PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
      if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
          intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
          intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"));
          context.startActivity(intent);
      }
    }
  }
  ```

It will ask user to exclude your app from battery optimization .

Comment: including the line "intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));" can get your application blocked by google play. use it without this line

Comment: I thought Google looks at this setting unfavorably now?

Comment: @kfir can you please provide the reason for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, check it, feel free to ask

**File AndroidManifest.xml**

```
// dont forget this permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

**Functions to check(boolean) and to request permission**

```
// to check if the app has the permission or not
fun checkBatteryLifePermission(): Boolean {
    try {
        val pm: PowerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val result = pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(this.packageName)
        return result
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        println(e)
    }
    return false
}

// Request permission to ignore optimization
@SuppressLint("BatteryLife")
fun requestBatteryOptimizationPermission() {
    try {
        val intent = Intent()
        // intent.action = Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        launcher.launch(intent)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        println(e)
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
if (!checkBatteryLifePermission()) {
    requestBatteryOptimizationPermission()
}
```